# Elasticsearch - Merge multiple match phrases

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, dsl, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the below query, and it's working fine. But my requirement states that I could have multiple phrases which I need to match in the **OR** condition, Is there any way I can shorten the query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "primaryTags": {
              "query": "Audience1",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "secondaryTags": {
              "query": "Audience1",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "primaryTags": {
              "query": "Audience2",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "secondaryTags": {
              "query": "Audience2",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "1",
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I would have to keep adding two match phrases primary and secondary with every new phrase coming in.
Is there a way to have all the phrases for primary and secondary in one condition respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [multi_match query with type phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html). Try out the below search query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Audience1",
                        "fields": [
                            "primaryTags^2",
                            "secondaryTags^3"
                        ],
                        "type": "phrase"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Audience2",
                        "fields": [
                            "primaryTags^2",
                            "secondaryTags^3"
                        ],
                        "type": "phrase"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```